# Update ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>>

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

How do I update `ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>>`?
quantity is `String`

```
values.get(position).put(KEY_POSITION, quantity);
```

Error:

> The method put(String, capture#11-of ?) in the type
>   HashMap is not applicable for the arguments
>   (String, String)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So problem is related into logic of wildcards. Wildcard means "value type parameter can be anything" so `HashMap<String, ?>` is valid but here you're not able to put a String value into it.

**Note:** `HashMap<String, ?>` is same as `HashMap<String, ? extends Object>` so **`?`** can be any type of class but **String** cannot be any type of class. This is reason of your error.

You need to make small change:

```
HashMap<String, ? super String>
```

Or as suggested @user902383 directly change<sup>1</sup> (with same result) it into:

```
HashMap<String, String>
```

Now it will accept Strings.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>String class is final (you can't extend from it) - for this reason it's better to use `HashMap<String, String>` First approach with `HashMap<String, ? super String>` is "useless" since you're not able to extend from String class.</sub>

Comment: `HashMap<String, ? super String>` can be replaced with `HashMap<String, String>` with same result as `String` is final and cant be extended

Comment: @lordzden so if it works, can you accept answer as working one also for others? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the wildcard "?". This is basically an unknown type. You should probably use `String` type instead, or `Object` if you need a more generic type. Like so:

`ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`

You can read more about it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html
and here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/morefun.html

Hope it helps.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

this is code;

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> hashArray=new 
hashArray.get(index).remove("key");
hashArray.get(index).put("key","value");
```

ok

Answer (score -1):

You can try toString implemented in the type of "quantity".

Otherwise simply, quantity + ""

Comment: The problem is that `String` is not of type `?`. It has nothing to do with `quantity` not being a `String`.